# What happens if you don't terminate the connection to the dreamers in Ward 16?

Tags: chronos

Spoilers, in case you haven't gotten to Ward 16.

> I managed to sneak into Ward 16 fairly early in the game and was able to terminate one of the dreamers (by using the computer terminal nearby). I thought this would have the effect of skipping a boss fight, but I still fought all three by the end of the game.

My question is: what changes if you choose not to kill that character?

Comment: While the attempts to prevent spoilers are appreciated, you should ask what you want to know. If your question doesn't make sense without the spoilers, it's a really good indicator they shouldn't be there.

Comment: I don't quite understand - should I just put the spoilers in the title, then?

Comment: If you're beating around the bush in an effort to avoid spoiling, yup.  Just ask it straight out.  Your question should make sense without the spoilers.  See [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10838/20456) for a basic guideline.

Answer (score 1):

So I terminated the dreamer connected to the third world, and the result seemed like the boss fight started at half health. I didn't do that for the other dreamers and those fights were full health bosses. So far that's the only thing that's happened and I would bet it's the only thing that will happen. So if you are struggling with a fight, terminate the dreamer to make it easier on yourself.